# Lagrange's best approximations law proof by contradiction doubt

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, diophantine-approximation

In the proof of Lagrange's best approximations law it is stated that the system of equations
$$
xp_n+yp_{n+1}=p\\
xq_n+yq_{n+1}=q\\
$$
where $\dfrac{p_n}{q_n}$ is the rational is a convergent of the continued fraction of a real number $\alpha$, has integer solutions $x, y$ since $p_nq_{n+1}-p_{n+1}q_n=(-1)^n$.

Please check [CONTINUED FRACTIONS BEST APPROXIMATIONS](http://edshare.soton.ac.uk/2387/1/Bestapprox.pdf)

I understand that the system of equations can be written as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}p_n&p_{n+1}\\q_n&q_{n+1}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}p\\q\end{bmatrix}
$$
which has a solution if $\begin{vmatrix}p_n&p_{n+1}\\q_n&q_{n+1}\end{vmatrix}=p_nq_{n+1}-p_{n+1}q_n\neq 0$

How do we know that this system has integer solutions ?

Comment: do you know how to find the inverse of a 2 by 2 matrix?

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks. $$
\begin{bmatrix}p_n&p_{n+1}\\q_n&q_{n+1}\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}p\\q\end{bmatrix}=\frac{\begin{bmatrix}q_{n+1}&-p_{n+1}\\-q_n&p_{n}\end{bmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}p_n&p_{n+1}\\q_n&q_{n+1}\end{vmatrix}}\begin{bmatrix}p\\q\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{(-1)^n}\begin{bmatrix}q_{n+1}&-p_{n+1}\\-q_n&p_{n}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}p\\q\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{(-1)^n}\begin{bmatrix}pq_{n+1}-qp_{n+1}\\-pq_n+qp_n\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}
$$, sum of products of integers is an integer, right ?

Comment: @WillJagy i was thinking abt it in terms of solution of diophantine equations and all.

Comment: yes. The point is that the determinant of the matrix is $\pm 1$

Comment: @WillJagy The statement of the theorem says $\alpha$ is an irrational number, bu I do not see anywhere in the proof we use that, so does the theorem applies to all real numbers ?